# Run NUnit test on build server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nunit, teamcity

I am using VS2010 and have TeamCity 7.1.2.

I do not have the ability to upgrade their versions but i want to have the ability 
to run my unit tests created with NUnit on my build server.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to set up NUnit tests reporting in TeamCity is to add [NUnit build runner](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/NUnit) as one of the steps to your build configuration and specify there all the required parameters.
You may find [Teamcity NUnit Support](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/NUnit+Support#) useful.